# Could vs Might vs May

Tags: modal-verbs, british-english

Which one of the following is commonly used in daily British English conversation?

> - The story **could** be true, but I don't think it is.
> - The story **might** be true, but I don't think it is.
> - The story **may** be true, but I don't think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The story could be true, but I don't think it is.

This simply means it is plausible. It is physically possible for the person to have done the deed. However, in NAm, could/would and may are practically interchangeable. It's nitpicking to correct a person who uses *could* when they technically should use *would* or *may*.

> The story might be true, but I don't think it is.

*Might* is the past tense of *may*. It works just fine in this sentence. I cannot imagine it would change with more context.

> The story may be true, but I don't think it is.

*May* is the present tense of *might*. It works just fine in this sentence. I cannot imagine it would change with more context.

Comment: In this instance *might* is NOT the past of *may* We can express possibility in the past  by using either "could", "might" or "may" but the sentence needs to be changed: *The story **may / might / could have been*** true, but I don't think it ***was***. Using "would" in place of "may" or "could" changes the meaning, and, it would be ungrammatical "The story would be true, but I don't think it is.” NO

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as a native American English speaker, here's my understanding:

**Could** - Possible with no inference whether event/behavior is likely or not.
**Might** - Probable; Sometimes used conditionally "Might work/happen IF."
**Might-Could** - Colloquial Southern phrase that guys use in their man caves.
**Can** - Could but implies that you want it to happen or a warning that it could.
**May** - Permission granted; Often improperly used to mean "might."

**Should** - Assertive favorable judgement about suitability, or proper behavior.
**Ought** - Archaic term for "should" as used in the expression "Ought to."
**Would** - Conditional "could," or preceding excuse/reason for failure/inaction.
**Coulda-Shoulda-Woulda** - Colloquial: "Stop making excuses" (AKA "whatever").

Answer (score 1):

> The story could be true, but I don't think it is.

==> I read this as "It is entirely possible that the story is true, however I do not think it is". The speaker is casting doubt on the story's verity, as it has not yet been decided.

> The story might be true, but I don't think it is.

==> I read this as "It is possible the story has already been proven true but I have not heard. Until I know otherwise, I will believe the story is not true". The speaker remains skeptical without any solid word on the story's verity.

> The story may be true, but I don't think it is.

==> I read this as "I do not think the story is true although it has already been proven so." The speaker is taking a stance of cognitive dissonance in the face of solid verity.