# How to distinguish MAY from MIGHT?

Tags: difference, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, modality

I need to define what a given functional object is, what it looks like, what it is made of.

Should I say:

> It MAY be any kind of box, a metal box like a shoe box, or a cardboard box like a cookie box. It MAY be hidden anywhere in the house or garden or in the neighbourhood.

or

> It MIGHT be a metal box like a shoe box, or a cardboard box like a cookie box. It MIGHT be hidden anywhere in the house or garden or in the neighbourhood.

I can't make out the difference or which one is better with what meaning effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could vs Might vs May](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119647/could-vs-might-vs-may)

Answer (score 1):

The article linked in the comments - [Could vs Might vs May](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119647/could-vs-might-vs-may) - mentions that *might* is the past tense of *may*.  The thing is, *might* and *may* are "modals" and modals don't really have tense.

> I might go to the park today.

> I may go to the park today.

These are both OK to say and neither of these are past or present tense.

*X may Y* means X *allows* or *gives permission* for Y to exist or happen.

*X might Y* means that Y will happen if X wants to.

Both of these are often used in place of *can* or *could*.  *May* is often used in the same sense as *might*, but not vice versa - especially when someone's asking for permission directly - e.g. "May I go to the park?"

So ...

> It MAY be any kind of box, a metal box like a shoe box, or a cardboard box like a cookie box

One possible meaning: you are asking someone to give you a box, and letting them know the acceptable types of boxes (the boxes you provide "permission" to receive).

Another possible meaning: synonymous with *can*.

> It MIGHT be any kind of box, a metal box like a shoe box, or a cardboard box like a cookie box

So in this sentence, no one asked for a box, or is trying to gateway receiving a box.  We're probably looking for a box that is lost or sometihng like that.

Modals in English are an inexact thing--especially if someone is trying to be polite or defer to authority--so don't over think it.  However *might* is almost never used to directly request permission for something.

Comment: Several modals (notably _would_ and _could_ are historically past tense, and do indeed function as the past of others (_will_ and _can_) in some contexts, such as back-shifting; but they have their own independent existence as well. _Might_ did function as the past of _may_ in this way fairly recently - certainly you'll find _He asked if he might go_ in books up to the mid-20th century. But it is an old-fashioned use now.

Comment: I get it, but which one MAY or MIGHT, or maybe neither of them, is most to the point in the context of a definition?